# Why does 2 get printed if 2%2 is 0?

Tags: python

In summary, I know 2 is a prime number because it is divisible by 1 and itself but why does it still print 2 if 2%2 = 0 and the range is between 2 and the number you're checking, which in this case is 2. Shouldn't it start at 3?

```
for num in range (1, 1000):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2, num):
            if (num % i ) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print (num)
```

I expected 3 to be the first output.

Comment: range() does not include the second endpoint.  range(2,2) is empty.

Comment: @Max is correct, also, I'm not sure if this is intentional but should the else be indented to line up with the second if ? This will produce different results again.

Comment: So does it just finds the next divisible number in the num range (1, 1000) for example 2%3 = 1 and just prints 2, or does it just figures there's no endpoint so the break condition can't be met and just prints 2?

Comment: Today I learned that in Python it's possible for a for-loop to have an else-clause:  http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html  (The code inside the else-clause will be executed after the for-loop completes, but only if the for-loop completed normally and not via the `break` keyword)

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava: `for` loops take an `else` clause. Your edit was incorrect. Editing indentation in Python questions is generally risky; instead, it's safer to ask the questioner to compare the indentation of the posted code to the code they actually ran. (The fact that the edit got approved by the questioner doesn't mean the edit was correct.)

Comment: Thank you @JeremyFriesner for the link, it further cleared my doubt.

Comment: @DumbAtMath: Indentation matters in Python. Indentation changes are not merely aesthetic. The edit you accepted completely changes the behavior of the code; instead of [printing primes from 2 to 999](https://ideone.com/29peWY), it just [prints the number 1](https://ideone.com/3Sxak2).

Comment: I was foolish, perhaps I expected it to behave like in C. Thank you @user2357112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2` is printed because `for i in range(2, num)` performs no iterations when `num == 2`.  This is because the second argument to `range()` is not included in the list that `range()` generates.  So for the `2` iteration of your outer loop, the equivalent iteration code is:

```
num = 2
if num > 1:
    for i in []:
        if (num % i ) == 0:
            break
    else:
        print (num)
```

which will print `2` since the 'break' line won't be executed.

Comment: Of course! Just like another answer here, python `for loops` include the first number but not the last, in this case first number is `2` and last number is `2` so in this case the range argument is not valid and there forth will execute the `else` statement. Now I understand why it's not common to add `else `statements in `for loops.`  Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python `for` loops include the first number, but exclude the last number. Because of this, the clause `for i in range(2,2)` won't actually return any numbers. This is why the number 2 gets printed in your `else` block.

It also helps to keep your `if` and `else` blocks at the same indent level to avoid confusing the computer.